# Translating Apache Rewrite to Tuckey urlrewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm using SEO4Ajax to enable SEO for my AJAX app. As such I need to implement a rewrite rule, as provided in their sample. However, I am using Tomcat on Openshift. I am thinking of using Tuckey URLRewriteFilter to implement the rewrite as a Filter instead.

Here's the Rewrite Rule in apache:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  _escaped_fragment_=  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://api.seo4ajax.com/{{my token}}/$1 [P,QSA,L]
```

Below is the sample rule defined in the Tuckey documentation.

```
<rule>
    <from>??</from>
    <to type="redirect">%{context-path}/??</to>
</rule>
```

I would greatly appreciate some help!!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but you can do something like this:

```
<rule>
    <condition name="_escaped_fragment_" type="parameter" operator="equal"></condition>
    <from>^/(.*)$</from>
    <to type="redirect" last="true">http://api.seo4ajax.com/[[API KEY]]/$1</to>
</rule>
```